# Data Access Layer in Asp.Net

Tags: c#-4.0, architecture, ado.net, data-access-layer

Am Afraid If am Overdoing things here.

We recently started a .Net project containig different Class Libraries for DAl,Services and DTO.

Question is about our DAL layer we wanted a clean and easily maintained Data access layer, We wanted go with Entity Framework 4.1.

So still not clear about what to opt for Plain ADO.Net using DAO and DAOImpl methodolgy or 
Entity Framework. 
Could any one please suggest the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much work you want to put into creating your own customized DAL. It is always better to use ADO.NET and your own implementations, but this also includes maintaining and optimizing it and treating complex cases such as concurrency, caching and the mapping of you BO, the DAL and the Database.

If you want to concentrate more on business value and functionality you might decide to go with Entity Framework (now 4.3 released and 5.0 to come). The advantage would be that you use a DAL that was carefully tested and that already contains solutions for concurrency, caching and mapping.

But I would hardly suggest using the Repository and Unit Of Work patterns on top of it to abstract the usage of Entity Framework out of your other layers. Then you would have the possibility to later completely change the underlying technologies without any impact on the other layers (you could replace EF with your own ADO.NET implementation if you see that the performance is not as good as it should be for example).

It depends on the type of application that you need to build and on its performance requirements. Using EF could really reduce your work and give you much quicker results. It also depends on the development teams capabilities. If you only have senior developers and architects working on the project then you will create you own DAL easily. But for beginners it is really hard to implement a good, optimized and robust DAL.

I hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

I've been using ADO.NET and DTO combination in DAL ever since i remember and i love the fact that i control the entire process of creating entities and methods. However that comes with the price of having to write classes for every entity and methods for every stored procedure. Which i don't mind, but recently i have discovered [PLINQO for LINQ to SQL](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks#plinqo) and I'm loving it. It gives you ease of creation/updating of Classes based on your Database schema while allowing for high levels of customization. Its basically LINQ2SQL on steroids.
I also liked [nHibernate](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateForNET?_sscc=t) but i think it had steeper learning curve than PLINQO.

I'd give PLINQO a try if i was you

Comment: It needs Codesmith tools yes, which is commercial but it is affordable